# unable to convert my data to jquery variable in tree replacing " with &quot in jquery laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, tree, laravel-blade

i have a variable in blade {{$data}}.
i want to use it in jquery variable in tree reference(https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/reference/tree/)

if i try `{{ str_replace(['";"'],[';'], json_encode([$data]))}}` in blade it gives

```
[{
             name: "ali", value: 88,
             joindate: ""11/09/2022", email: "{{\Auth::user()->email}}",
             photo: "01.png", level: 6,
             children: [{       
                 name: "salim", level: 1,
                 joindate: "11/09/2022", email: "sssss@lutota.com",
                 photo: "02.png", level: 4,
                 },]
         }];
```

when i copy this code in data variable like static text in jquery like

```
let data = [{
             name: "ali", value: 88,
             joindate: ""11/09/2022", email: "{{\Auth::user()->email}}",
             photo: "01.png", level: 6,
             children: [{       
                 name: "salim", level: 1,
                 joindate: "11/09/2022", email: "sssss@lutota.com",
                 photo: "02.png", level: 4,
                 },]
         }];
```

it works fine in tree but when i want to use variable instead of code like below it display nothing

```
let data = '{{json_encode([$data])}}';
```

nothing works...please help

Comment: show your controller code for $data.

Comment: thanks for replying 
controller is fine just want to know how to convert my blade variable in jquery
in console log data is displaying fine but unable to use it in let data variable

Comment: you just do this let data = {{json_encode($data)}}; in script

Comment: i didi this but not building the tree

Comment: in console.log data display fine but in let data not working as it should work

Comment: use this instead : let data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>; working on my end

Comment: @sherz Please don't post code in the comments, instead, [edit] your question and append additional information there. Thanks

Comment: thank you very much man how can i say wonderful thanks yo you "solute" @sumit kumar

Comment: can you please help me to correct tree i am getting only one level child i need multiple level child mean child of child adding my controller code to below comment so i will remove the comment after getting solution thanks in advance @Sumitkumar

Comment: will remove my comment when got answer
$user = \Auth::user();
        do {
             $data = [
            'name' => Auth::user()->name,
            'value' => Auth::user()->id,
        ];
            foreach($user->tree as $subtre){
                $data['children'][]  = [
                    'name' => $subtre->user->name,
                    'value' => $subtre->user->id,
                ];
                    }
                    $user = $subtre->user;
                }
        while (count($user->tree) > 0);

Comment: i am so sorry i am new how to mark it fixed?

Comment: kindly open a new thread with model, migration and controller code with how you want your data to be, it's hard to understand code here.

Comment: if user has multiple childrens so add an function which returns with hasMany(ModelName) and if user as grandChildrens make another function with hasManyThrough(ModelGC, ModelChildren), then in controller $user = User::with('children', 'grandchildren')->find(someid); that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace let data with this:

```
let data = {!! json_encode($data) !!};
```

or with this :

```
let data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
```

or with this :

```
let data = @json($data); //for blade only
```